# Вывести одни и те же (одинаковые) данные несколько раз подряд

Tags: mysql

[image: Таблица]

```
$q="Select * FROM tbl;
$res=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo $row['marka'];
}
```

Получаю -
титан
никель

А как получить данные в зависимости от количества,
т.е. -

титан
титан
титан
никель

Comment: ну организуйте внутри еще один цикл, в зависимости от `$row['shtuk']`

Comment: для сгрупированого запроса нужно **distinct** или **group by**, например `$q="select distinct marka from tbl"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - добавить счетчик с привязкой к штукам. А зачем вообще плодить дубли? 
А например, для печати этикеток к заказам.

```
$q="Select * FROM tbl;
$res=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
for ($i = 0; $i < $shtuk; $i++)
{
echo $row['marka'];
}
}
```